Power Automate SharePoint list get trigger check window end time?
I support a lot of Microsoft Power Automate Cloud Flows that uses the polling trigger to run against items that have been created or updated in  SharePoint lists.
When the flow has not run, I want to be able to get the details for the last trigger window end time, so I can check not when the flow last ran, but the last time the flow trigger checked if it had items it should run for.
For example if I have a list with 1000 items, and a flow that has been turned off but I am not sure when it was turned off, and I am looking at turning the flow back on. I want to be able to check when the trigger is going to start checking from before I turn the flow back on.
Does anyone know if there is a PowerShell cmdlet, a graph API, a Data Verse table, a hidden details page, or some way to get back the point the trigger has checked up to?

not answer the exact question, but as I experienced, when you switch back a flow, it collects all (or at least a lot of) the triggers which happened during the time it was switched off. This means that after you switch the flow back, it fires many times at once. My workaround is not to switch it off, but add a 'Terminate: Cancelled' action right after the trigger event. With this approach, you can monitor the trigger events (because the flow starts) and you can put the flow trigger metadata to an other list.
